# GitLab - Could not find 'mono' host

Tags: .net, docker, gitlab

Hi there i´m trying to use CI/CD in GITLAB and i´m prettey new to this.

I was able to create the following yml file

```
# Default image is docker:stable
image: docker:stable

# Define deployment stages
stages:
  - build   

# We use docker-in-docker (dind) for building docker images (build stage)
services:
  - docker:dind

# Build unit test on dotnet core sdk image  
build:
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
  script:    
    - cd TestRegressionNebra/   
    - dotnet restore "TestRegressionNebra.csproj"
    - dotnet build "TestRegressionNebra.csproj"       
    - 'dotnet test "TestRegressionNebra.csproj" --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath={assembly}-test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"'
  artifacts:
        when: always
        paths: 
            - ./**/*test-result.xml
        reports:
            junit: 
                - ./**/*test-result.xml    
  tags:
    - nebra
```

But when i run this it gives me this error :

**Test run for /builds/fm/ecommerce/qa/testregression/TestRegressionNebra/bin/Debug/net461/TestRegressionNebra.dll (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.11.0 Starting test execution, please wait... A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find 'mono' host. Make sure that 'mono' is installed on the machine and is available in PATH environment variable. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Helpers.DotnetHostHelper.GetMonoPath()**

When i run the same command in my personal PC no problems were found.

EDIT: My *.csproj file attached

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JunitXml.TestLogger" Version="3.0.98" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="94.0.4606.6100" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Common\Common.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration.Install" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Can you include more of the error log/message? The error mentions `mono`, but you dont have mono in your yaml at all. Any additional context to the error message would be very useful.

Comment: sure @omajid heres the log :

Test run for /builds/fm/ecommerce/qa/testregression/TestRegressionNebra/bin/Debug/net461/TestRegressionNebra.dll (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.11.0
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find 'mono' host. Make sure that 'mono' is installed on the machine and is available in PATH environment variable.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Helpers.DotnetHostHelper.GetMonoPath()

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the info there, thanks! The `net461` in the error is very strange. Is this a .NET Framework project or .NET Core/.NET 5 project? Could you share the project files? It would be good to know what `<TargetFramework>` is being targeted.

Comment: hi @omajid i´ve edit the question.

My project is a  .NET Framework project 

<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>

I´ve putted my *.csproj file in the question.

Comment: you can't build .net framework targets using the .net core sdk

Comment: hi @DanielA.White thanks for the input.

But in that case why can i run it without a problem in my personal PC??

if i run "dotnet test *.cproj it works fine, but inside the GitLab image no.

Sorry if it´s a "stupid" question but it´s the first time i´m using gitlab and Docker Images

Comment: @BrunoMachado docker uses Linux. Your personal pc is likely windows and the framework is installed

Comment: hi @DanielA.White

That´s correct i´m using Windows , that makes sense

Is there any way to run it in the docker ? what do i have to do to run my code there ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message (and some of the comments), it looks like you're using the wrong type of runner.

GitLab CI/CD is run on a GitLab Runner. If you want to run anything that relies on Windows or Windows packages, then you need to either [install a GitLab Runner on Windows](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html) or if you're using GitLab.com, then [use the Windows shared runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/build_cloud/windows_build_cloud.html).

The image you specified `image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` in the CI yaml will also need to have all the dependencies installed, or install the necessary ones as part of the `script` section.

I also recommend taking a look at the [dotnet CI example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/dotNET.gitlab-ci.yml) and [dotnet-core CI example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/dotNET-Core.gitlab-ci.yml). See the [CI/CD Examples docs page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

On cross platform projects if NET 6.0 and .NET Framework 4.72 are used on `Linux` then it's necessary install `mono` if it's needed to test on the .NET Framework 4.72 either. If only NET 6.0 is used on `Linux` then ignore the warning.